# Auto generated ID values in Symfony

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

Entity generated in  Symfony framework has an ID field, however this filed has no setters (setID()). Therefore the very first entry in ID field into the database after persist and flush is '0'. But the subsequent entries also happen to be '0'. How do I make sure that next entry into the database gets values like 1 and subsequently increasing by 1 for every entry. I am having Integrity constraint violation due to this problem.

Comment: Should be filled with the correct value after a persist and flush call. Show your code.

Answer (score 1):

Exemple of a valid id definition:

```
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Id field in you entity should have @Id annotation. This means that this field is  identifier/primary key. By default doctrine uses AUTO strategy, byt it can be changed. Take look on the [doctrine documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#identifiers-primary-keys).